# Is there a list of about: protocol urls that work with IE mobile?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there any about: protocols similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/The_about_protocol) but for IE?

I'm wondering if one can get any extra info or tweak any hidden settings from a stock IE mobile instance without installing plugins or apps.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile version of Internet Explorer does not have a page like "about:config".

However, this has changed with Edge. If you are using Windows 10 Mobile you can type *about:flags* in address bar and get access to advanced features.